# Given matrix $A$, decide the existence of a $k \times k$ matrix $X$ such that $X^n=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, matrix-equations, decision-problems

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with an identity element $1$. Is there a $k\times k$ matrix $X$ over $R$ such that
$$
X^n=
\overbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
 -1 & -1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
}^{\mathrm{A}}\ ? 
$$
If $k\leq n$, then the answer is no, since $A^2=O$, so $X^{2n}=O$. If the minimal polynomial of $X$ os $m(t)$, then $m(t)\mid t^{2n}$ and since $\deg m(t)\leq k$, it follows that $X^k=O$, so $X^n=O$, a contradiction. What can be said when $n<k$ ?

Comment: What is matrix $C$?

Comment: I meant $A$....sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @Minslack. So we may assume that $2n\leq k$ ?

Comment: My comment was wrong. Consider the linear application $X$ such that $X(e_3)=e_2-e_1$, $X(e_2)=X(e_1)=e_k$, and, if $4 \leq l \leq k$, $X(e_l)=e_{l-1})$. Then $X^k=0$ but $X^{k-1}$ has the form you look for.

Comment: What are the $e_i$'s ? The standard basis of $\mathbb R^k$ ?

Comment: The $e_i$ are a basis of a vector space of dimension $k$.

Comment: Note that if $R$ has characteristic not divisible by $2$, then [we can equivalently take](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%7D+*+%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C-1%7D%7D+*+%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C1%7D%7D) the upper-left block to be the Jordan form matrix
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let

- $J_m$ be the $m\times m$ (upper triangular) nilpotent Jordan block,
- $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th position and zeroes elsewhere,
- $P=P^{-1}$ be the permutation matrix for the transposition $\pmatrix{2&n+1}$, and
- $S=\pmatrix{-1&-1\\ 1&0}$, with $S^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&-1}$ also lies inside $M_k(R)$.

Then
\begin{aligned}
A&=\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&-1}\oplus0_{(k-2)\times(k-2)}\\
&=\left(S\oplus I_{k-2}\right)\left(J_2\oplus0_{(k-2)\times(k-2)}\right)\left(S^{-1}\oplus I_{k-2}\right)\\
&=\left(S\oplus I_{k-2}\right)PE_{1,n+1}P^{-1}\left(S^{-1}\oplus I_{k-2}\right)\\
&=\left(S\oplus I_{k-2}\right)P\left(J_{n+1}^n\oplus0_{(k-n-1)\times(k-n-1)}\right)P^{-1}\left(S^{-1}\oplus I_{k-2}\right)\\
&=\left[\left(S\oplus I_{k-2}\right)P\left(J_{n+1}\oplus0_{(k-n-1)\times(k-n-1)}\right)P^{-1}\left(S^{-1}\oplus I_{k-2}\right)\right]^{\,n}.\\
\end{aligned}